# Reverse sort the dictionary by value

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary, sorted ascendingly by value.

```
>>> x = {'foo': 2.01, 'bar': 4.11, 'qux':3.2, 'ail':1.2, 'dfa':0.03}
>>> sorted_x = sorted(x.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
>>> sorted_x
[('dfa', 0.029999999999999999), ('ail', 1.2), ('foo', 2.0099999999999998), ('qux', 3.2000000000000002), ('bar', 4.1100000000000003)]
```

How can I do sort it descendingly by value?
I tried this but prints nothing

```
>>> sorted_x.reverse()
>>>
```

Comment: Use `reverse=True` while sorting.

Comment: "I tried this but prints nothing" Did you try checking `sorted_x` after that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `reverse=True` when you're sorting:

```
>>> sorted(x.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

[('bar', 4.11), ('qux', 3.2), ('foo', 2.01), ('ail', 1.2), ('dfa', 0.03)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [143]:

import operator
x = {'foo': 2.01, 'bar': 4.11, 'qux':3.2, 'ail':1.2, 'dfa':0.03}
sorted_x = sorted(x.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
sorted_x
Out[143]:
[('bar', 4.11), ('qux', 3.2), ('foo', 2.01), ('ail', 1.2), ('dfa', 0.03)]
```

Comment: why would you both flag the question as duplicate and give an answer?

Comment: @njzk2 I posted the answer first and then saw the duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> x = {'foo': 2.01, 'bar': 4.11, 'qux':3.2, 'ail':1.2, 'dfa':0.03}
>>> sorted_x = sorted(x.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
>>> sorted_x
[('bar', 4.11), ('qux', 3.2), ('foo', 2.01), ('ail', 1.2), ('dfa', 0.03)]
```